# Удаление строки из richTextBox

Tags: c++-cli

Как можно удалить определенную, к примеру, 5-ю строку из RichTextBox? Не засовывая содержимое в массив и оттуда удаляя строку?

**C++ CLI**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На C# (на C++/CLI аналогично)

```
int from = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
int amount = rtb.Lines[line].Length;

if (line < rtb.Lines.Length - 1) {
    amount += rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) -
        ((from + amount - 1) + 1);
}

rtb.Text = rtb.Text.Remove(from, amount);
```

В листинге rtb - компонент, line - номер строки, которая должна быть удалена.